# ConvergenceWarning when running cross validation with SVM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I tried to train a LinearSVC model and evaluate it with `cross_val_score` on a linearly separable dataset that I created, but I'm getting an error.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# creating the dataset
x1          = 2 * np.random.rand(100, 1)
y1          = 5 + 3 * x1 + np.random.randn(100, 1)
lable1  = np.zeros((100, 1))

x2          = 2 * np.random.rand(100, 1)
y2          = 15 + 3 * x2 + np.random.randn(100, 1)
lable2  = np.ones((100, 1))

x       = np.concatenate((x1, x2))
y       = np.concatenate((y1, y2))
lable = np.concatenate((lable1, lable2))

x       = np.reshape(x, (len(x),))
y       = np.reshape(y, (len(y),))
lable = np.reshape(lable, (len(lable),))

d   = {'x':x, 'y':y, 'lable':lable}
df  = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.plot(kind="scatter", x="x", y="y")



# preparing data and model
train_set, test_set = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
X = train_set.drop("lable", axis=1)
y = train_set["lable"].copy()

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(X)

linear_svc = LinearSVC(C=5, loss="hinge", random_state=42)
linear_svc.fit(X, y)



# evaluation
scores = cross_val_score(linear_svc, X, y, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10)
rmse_scores = np.sqrt(-scores)
print("Mean:", rmse_scores.mean())
```

[image]

Output:

> Mean: 0.0
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py:947: ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number of iterations.
> "the number of iterations.", ConvergenceWarning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error, but a warning, and it already contains some advice:

> increase the number of iterations

which by default is 1000 ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html)).

Moreover, `LinearSVC` is a classifier, so using `scoring="neg_mean_squared_error"` (i.e. a regression metric) in `cross_val_score` makes no sense; see the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#the-scoring-parameter-defining-model-evaluation-rules) for a rough list of relevant metrics per kind of problem.

So, with the following changes:

```
linear_svc = LinearSVC(C=5, loss="hinge", random_state=42, max_iter=100000)
scores = cross_val_score(linear_svc, X, y, scoring="accuracy", cv=10)
```

your code runs OK without any error or warning.